# Java - confirming a match at a specific index in a string

Tags: java, string, charat

Problem: Confirm if a specific character is at a specific index point of a string. For example, 'Hello' - is character H at index 0. I have managed to get this to work (as shown below). My issue is trying to add logical operators 'or' - || to allow for multiple options.

For example, at index 0, the letter could be H **or** M

The below works for confirming 'H' is at index '0'

```
if (myword.charAt(0)==('H')){
    System.out.println("True");
}    
else {
    System.out.println("False");
}
```

HOWEVER

if I then try to add a logical operator, this doesn't work and I just can't work out how to add logical operators to these type of scenarios.

```
if (myword.charAt(0)==('H')||('M')){
    System.out.println("True");
}    
else {
    System.out.println("False");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (myword.charAt(0)=='H' || myword.charAt(0)== 'M'){
  System.out.println("True");
} else {
  System.out.println("False");
}
```

Or

```
System.out.println(
  myword.charAt(0)=='H' || myword.charAt(0)== 'M'
);
```

Comment: Please give explanation, a code-only answer is something of very low quality

Comment: Thank you so much - this now makes it clearer how to be using these operators!